How do I get @variables in a sql query to stay set when I export the query results to cvs from phpmyadmin?
I'm using phpmyadmin.
I have a query like this
set @months := '36';
select bla, bla, bla
From tables
where date = @months;
Runs great from the sql tab.  When the results come up I hit export at the bottom of the results.  Then select csv, etc. go.  It reruns the query but it has lost the @variable so no results show.
Is there a way to have it rerun the set @months in the export?
Of course, I can do a mass search and replace and replace all the @months with 36 and use that.
